# How center the new location of Google Map on React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-map-react

I use *google-map-react* to display a Google Map with Custom Marker to show a location.

Can i change the location succesfully, its mean, passing lat and lng to the map component and put the marker on the new location, butthe view of the map its still on the older location.

How can i center on the new location?

**Main Component**

Lat and Lng starts with a coordinates, whit setState put a new

Don't put the entire component but it's the way I call the map

```
return (
    <div className="main">
        <div className="main__map">
            <TheMap center={[this.state.lat, this.state.lng]} />
        </div>
    </div>
)
```

**TheMap Component**

```
import React,{useState , useEffect} from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

function TheMap(props){
    const [cordinates , setCordinates] = useState(props);
    const MyCustomMarker = () => <span class="material-icons">place</span>;

    useEffect(() => {
       setCordinates(props);
    }, [props])

    return(
        <GoogleMapReact
            yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
            bootstrapURLKeys={{key:'THE KEY'}}
            defaultZoom={16}
            center={cordinates.center}
        >
            <MyCustomMarker
                lat={cordinates.center[0]}
                lng={cordinates.center[1]}
            />
        </GoogleMapReact>
    )
}

export default TheMap
```

Answer (score 3):

You should set the default `coordinates` to any location by default, for example `[10.00, 10.00]`, then change the dependency array of useEffect to `[props.center]`, finally set the coordinates value to `props.center`.

### The map component

```js
import React,{useState , useEffect} from 'react';
import GoogleMapReact from 'google-map-react';

function TheMap(props){
    const [cordinates , setCordinates] = useState([10, 10]);
    const MyCustomMarker = () => <span class="material-icons">place</span>;

    useEffect(() => {
       setCordinates(props.center);
    }, [props.center])

    return(
        <GoogleMapReact
            yesIWantToUseGoogleMapApiInternals={true}
            bootstrapURLKeys={{key:'THE KEY'}}
            defaultZoom={16}
            center={cordinates}
        >
            <MyCustomMarker
                lat={cordinates[0]}
                lng={cordinates[1]}
            />
        </GoogleMapReact>
    )
}

export default TheMap
```

Comment: In fact on the Main Component when call TheMap Component the lat and lng starts with values.

So, my problem still here, i change and send the new location corretly, and the marker changes, but the map not move to the new one

Comment: Did you verify the GoogleMapReact props? I'm seeing in the repo it has to be defaultCenter, not center. https://github.com/google-map-react/google-map-react

Comment: I have the same issue. @AlexisOlveres can you solve the problem?

Answer (score 1):

You need to ensure that in
center={coordinates}
coordinates is a new object and not only the same object with just changed values of lat and lng. Otherwise react will not recognize it as changed.
If it doesn't work in the above then the same object was passed already to props.center.

Answer (score 1):

This happens because you are sending the latitude and longitude as strings, if you inspect the GoogleMapReac element from the reactdevtools and remove the quotes around the latitude and longitude, then it will automatically center the location on the map.

**lat and long must be of type Number**